# Is using FacetGrid or relplot for multiple time-series lineplots with labels possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to visually represent a set of policies with lineplots, seperated by a label determined through clustering. The data has points through Jan to May and a label.
For simplicity I have changed it to the following test data:

```
test_data = [[100,20,0,0,0,1],[20,20,80,100,100,2],[100,120,120,150,120,2],[150,150,150,50,0,1],
[75,20,30,40,30,1],[200,200,75,10,5,2]]
idx_test = ["pol1","pol2","pol3","pol4","pol5","pol6"]
df_stack = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Jan", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "May", "Label"], index=idx_test, data=test_data)
```

Preferably I would like sub-lineplots of the policies grouped by label. However I am having an issue with the way may data is collated.

With `sns.lineplot` I need to transpose the dataframe, however the label column then can no longer be used by FacetGrid or relplot.

I can get all lineplots on one figure:

```
df_stack2= df_stack.drop("Label", axis=1)
sns.lineplot(data=df_stack2.T, dashes=False, legend=False, sort=False)
```

And I can get the basics of a FacetGrid:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_stack, col="Label")
```

Can anyone help me work out how to map the lineplots?

Comment: There is no cluster data in your data. What are you assuming to be the clusters?

Comment: The labels. So in this instance i have 2 clusters (1,2)

Answer (score 2):

To get round the above problem, I found that using `pd.melt()` helped structure my data so that I could use the `sns.FacetGrid()`.

```
df_stack.rename(columns={"index":"Pols"}, inplace=True)
melted = pd.melt(df_stack, id_vars=["Pols","Label"])

g = sns.FacetGrid(melted, col="Label", col_wrap=3, hue="Pols")
g.map(sns.lineplot, "variable", "value", sort=False)
```

Hope that helps some others lost in the Seaborn/Pandas labyrinth.